# Erro no Spring ao iniciar o servidor

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jsp, maven, tomcat

Importei um projeto Maven que funcionava perfeitamente antes, porém agora estou com ele dando erro.

Toda vez que eu tento arrumar esse erro, eu fico trocando as versões do Java, excluindo e importando novamente e etc.

**Dependências:**

```
</parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<!-- BEGIN DEPENDENCIES -->
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- BEGIN SPRING MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END SPRING MVC -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- BEGIN SPRING BOOT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END SPRING BOOT -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- BEGIN HAKARICP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END HAKARICP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- BEGIN APACHE COMMONS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END APACHE COMMONS -->
    <!-- BEGIN COMMONS FILE UPLOAD -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END COMMONS FILE UPLOAD -->
    <!-- BEGIN JUNIT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END JUNIT -->
    <!-- BEGIN MYSQL CONNECTOR -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END MYSQL CONNECTOR -->
</dependencies>
<!-- END DEPENDENCIES -->
```

**Mensagem de erro:**

> INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.78 jul 01,
>   2017 10:02:50 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase
>   createSecureRandom INFORMAÇÕES: Creation of SecureRandom instance for
>   session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [132] milliseconds. jul
>   01, 2017 10:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   filterStart GRAVE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:495)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:477)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4958)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5652)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> jul 01, 2017 10:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal GRAVE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details
>   will be found in the appropriate container log file jul 01, 2017
>   10:02:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>   GRAVE: Context [/arquivo] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: Primeiro, não misture dependências do Spring Boot com as do Spring Framework, pode rolar muitos conflitos. Na exceção parece que o problema é relacionado ao Spring Security.

Comment: @romarcio então como fazer para separá-las?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu resolvi assim:

1. [Adicione o Java as Variáveis de Ambiente](http://www.devmedia.com.br/preparacao-do-ambiente-para-desenvolvimento-em-java/25188);
2. Remova o projeto e delete a pasta da workspace;
3. Crie uma nova workspace (assim você terá as configurações default);
4. Importe o projeto como *Java Project* ao invés de *Maven Project*;
5. Verifique na aba *Markers* se há algum erro no projeto, caso haja, clique com o botão direito e vá na opção *Quick Fix*;
6. Adicione um servidor usando a configuração default da JRE (certifique-se que o projeto está rodando com a JRE da pasta JDK);
7. Clique com o botão direito do mouse no projeto, vá na opção *Run As*, selecione *Maven Clean* e logo após *Maven Install*;
8. Clique no projeto e dê `ALT + F5`;
9. Vá em na aba *Servers*, clique com o botão direito no servidor e selecione *Publish*;
10. Inicie o servidor;